# Jenkins Sonar Integration as post build action

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am unable to add Sonar as a post build action in Jenkins.
When I try to add build action, I get the option "Execute SonarQube Scanner" but when I try to add post-build action, I dont get that option.
Jenkins version - 2.39
SonarQube version - 5.6
SonarQube Scanner for jenkins plugin - 2.5

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to launch a Sonar analysis is to call Sonar as a Maven goal.

Here are my settings on Jenkins 1.6.

Build environnement section:

[image]

Maven goals:

```
mvn clean -U install findbugs:findbugs $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
```

And of course, you have to configure your Sonar instance in the global settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Post Build Action is deprecated. You should use build steps. In this case, simply put the desired build step at the end of your build.